# Same value occuring multiple times

Tags: ssms

I am trying to run a query similar to the following one

```
"select * from 

(select datepart(wk,date)as week,count(*),platform 

from school 

where year(date) = 2015

group by datepart(wk,date)) a

full outer join

(select datepart(wk,date) as week,count(*),platform 

from school 

where year(date) = 2014

group by datepart(wk,date)) b

on b.week = a.week

order by b.week "
```

I am getting same values multiple times as a result.

Can anyone suggest me what is the problem...

Thank You

Comment: Can you give us a snippet of the output?

Comment: Sorry but it is my school's data I am working on. Hence Can not provide the output snippet..

Comment: ok, which value is occurring multiple times then?

Comment: Platform values are occuring multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed platform out of the group by:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT DATEPART(wk,[date]) AS [week]
    ,COUNT(*)
    ,[platform] 
  FROM [school] 
  WHERE YEAR([date]) = 2015
  GROUP BY DATEPART(wk,[date]), [platform]
) [a]
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT DATEPART(wk,[date]) AS [week]
    ,COUNT(*)
    ,[platform] 
  FROM [school] 
  WHERE YEAR([date]) = 2014
  GROUP BY DATEPART(wk,[date]), [platform]
) [b]
ON [b].[week] = [a].[week]
ORDER BY [b].[week]
```